# How to embed facebook go live video broadcast in website?

Tags: facebook, user-interface, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to embed live video to my website which is done live with go live facebook feature. SO that i need to embed that go live video player to my website. Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: First hit on Google gives me https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player

Comment: Thank you! but actually i was searching for go live feature embed on my website. In this we can only get a particular video. When every time i go live that video must be broadcast to my website. Thank you.